# Overriding GlobalNavigation Delegate control

Tags: navigation, user-controls, delegate

I have overridden the GlobalNavigation delegate control and have been very pleased with the results.  Now I would like to remove my global navigation from application pages that display in iframes (check permissions form, new site form, etc...).

I do not want to exclude all pages in the layouts folder though because I want my global navigation to display on the site settings page, osssearchresults.aspx, etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this article from Randy Drisgill.  It's exactly what you need.  Add the s4-notdlg css class to each div you want to hide in dialogs.

http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-2-custom-master.html

Comment: That's actually awesome, I need to do exactly this in something I'm working on (though it's not a delegate control, I need the same behaviour).